# PHP regex match data between html

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

i have created a regex, that actually extracts the data what i need, but it also includes ">" character, how do i get rid of it? Here's the code.

```
<?php

$content = file_get_contents('www.example.com');
$pattern = "/>([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3})/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches);
echo $matches[0][2];

?>
```

and the HTML to extract from

```
<td style="text-align:right" class="row">23.020</td>
```

it gives me the "<23.020" but what i need is "23.020"
i know it's a n00b question, but how do i get rid of the "<"

Answer (score 2):

```
$content = '<td style="text-align:right" class="row">23.020</td>';
$pattern = "/>([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3})/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

will give you

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) ">23.020"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "23.020"
  }
}
```

So simply use `$matches[1][0]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match something in a regex, but not capture it, then you can use an "[assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)". For your string it would be a `(?<=[>])` lookbehind.

```
 /(?<=>)([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3})/
```

In your case however, you already have a capture group which excludes the `>` anchor. You just need to access the right result group then:

```
 echo $matches[1][2];
```

The `[1]` refers to the inner `(...)` parens group, whereas your `[0]` would return the complete match.

Comment: You can also have a look at [`PREG_SET_ORDER`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php#~PREG_SET_ORDER) as parameter. That's a more logical grouping and in some cases easier to work with.